# Add all API response in one array Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add all response of API in one array,how can i add all response in array?
Following are my code for get api.
I want to get response in array and use that array in listview length etc.

```
Future<UserPost> getUserPost() async {

    var url =
        "https://myapi.com/getUserPost.php?page=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    var _apiData = UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);

    //totalPage = _apiData.totalPages as int?;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      if(isRefersh == true){
        setState((){
          isRefersh = false;
        });
        refreshController.refreshCompleted();
        return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
      }
      else{
        print(_apiData.hasNextPage.toString());
        if(_apiData.hasNextPage == 0){
          refreshController.loadNoData();
        }else{
          refreshController.loadComplete();
        }
        return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
      }

    } else {
      return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
    }
  }
```

Following are MY API Response. This all response i want to add in one array.

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": "found",
  "data": [
    {
      "ref_id": "32",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "Shanti baugh hall ",
      "city_name": "Mahuva",
      "description": "All azadars are invited please come on time. We will together in azadari at same time.\njazakallah ",
      "end_date": "30-12-2022",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG2067578631.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "Molana Roman Rizvi sahab",
      "postDateTime": "14-12-2022 12:07 PM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "after majlis nayaze hussain as",
      "start_date": "15-12-2022",
      "time": "1:30 PM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani"
    },
    {
      "ref_id": "29",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "Sakina Hall",
      "city_name": "Mahuva",
      "description": "detail is detail and time is also time so just come",
      "end_date": "10-12-2022",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG380256195.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "Mohammad ali abedi sahab",
      "postDateTime": "01-12-2022 11:17 PM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "After majlis nayaz",
      "start_date": "06-12-2022",
      "time": "9:15 PM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani"
    },
    {
      "ref_id": "31",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "\u0a85\u0aac\u0ac2\u0aa4\u0abe\u0ab2\u0abf\u0aac \u0ab9\u0acb\u0ab2",
      "city_name": "\u0aae\u0ab9\u0ac1\u0ab5\u0abe",
      "description": "\u0aae\u0ab9\u0ac1\u0ab5\u0abe \u0aae\u0abe\u0a82 \u0aaa\u0ac7\u0ab9\u0ab2\u0ac0 \u0ab5\u0abe\u0ab0 \u0aa4\u0ab6\u0acd\u0ab0\u0ac0\u0aab \u0ab2\u0abe\u0ab5\u0ac0 \u0ab0\u0ab9\u0acd\u0aaf\u0abe \u0a9b\u0ac7.",
      "end_date": "07-12-2022",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG481705423.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "\u0aae\u0acb\u0ab2\u0abe \u0aa8\u0abe \u0aae\u0ac3\u0aa4\u0ac1\u0a9d\u0abe (\u0aad\u0abe\u0ab5\u0aa8\u0a97\u0ab0)",
      "postDateTime": "04-12-2022 06:55 PM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "\u0ab9\u0ab0 \u0aae\u0a9c\u0ab2\u0ac0\u0ab8 \u0aac\u0abe\u0aa6 \u0aa8\u0acd\u0aaf\u0abe\u0a9d\u0ac7 \u0ab9\u0ac1\u0ab8\u0ac8\u0aa8 (\u0a85.\u0ab8) \u0ab0\u0abe\u0a96\u0ac7\u0ab2 \u0a9b\u0ac7.",
      "start_date": "06-12-2022",
      "time": "9:00 PM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani"
    }
  ],
  "totalPosts": "5",
  "totalPages": 2,
  "perPageLimit": 3,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "hasNextPage": 1
}

}
```

Futher i want to use the array in pagination format so kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
List<UserPost> fetchData = [];
  List<UserPost> allFetchData = [];
  
  
  getUserPost() async {
  
 var url =
        "https://myapi.com/getUserPost.php?page=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    fetchData = UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
    
    allFetchData = allFetchData + fetchData; // this will update every time when api will be called
    // and try to fetch "allFetchData" on your ui
  }
```

Comment: Not working. it gives following errors. ( V/ImeFocusController(10767): onWindowFocus: DecorView@9ab4fcd[MainActivity] softInputMode=STATE_UNSPECIFIED|ADJUST_RESIZE|IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION
V/ImeFocusController(10767): Restarting due to isRestartOnNextWindowFocus as true
D/ImeFocusController(10767): onViewFocusChanged, view=DecorView@9ab4fcd[MainActivity], mServedView=null
V/ImeFocusController(10767): checkFocus: view=null next=DecorView@9ab4fcd[MainActivity] force=true package=<none> )

Comment: please add your api response pattern

Comment: api response pattern added

Comment: added api response in question